# How to skip last row in a table JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function where I perform the sum of a value in each row, but in my table the last row I have an option to add more rows, so when I do the count the last value return me, Nan, because I don't have values there, so anyone know how can I skip this last row?
This is my js:

```
function CalcularTotal () {
    var subtotal = 0;
    var total = 0;
    $("#tPedidos TBODY TR").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);

            //Valor de Precio
            Precio = row.find("TD").eq(1).find('input').val();

            //Valor de Cantidad
            CantidadPedido = row.find("TD").eq(2).find('input').val();

            //subtotal de PRECIO * CAntidad y Total de cada fila
            subtotal = Precio * CantidadPedido;
            total += Number(subtotal);
            console.log(total);                
        });

        //Asignarle el valor al input
        $("#tot").val(total);
        //console.log(total);          
}
```

Comment: Could you add a class to the rows you do want to count so then you can just use `$('#tPedidos tr.countable')`

Comment: in each function you can have index so ignore if index and the length of $("#tPedidos TBODY TR") - 1 is same, or you can simply check for NAN values

Comment: what if you use a `tfoot` tag for the last row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
function CalcularTotal () {
var subtotal = 0;
var total = 0;
var trLength = $("#tPedidos TBODY TR").length;
$("#tPedidos TBODY TR").each(function (index) {

       if (index === (trLength - 1)){
          return
       }

       var row = $(this);

        //Valor de Precio
        Precio = row.find("TD").eq(1).find('input').val();

        //Valor de Cantidad
        CantidadPedido = row.find("TD").eq(2).find('input').val();

        //subtotal de PRECIO * CAntidad y Total de cada fila
        subtotal = Precio * CantidadPedido;
        total += Number(subtotal);
        console.log(total);                
    });

    //Asignarle el valor al input
    $("#tot").val(total);
    //console.log(total);          
}
```

Comment: Ok this one works! thank you so much, and thanks to everyone who helped me too

Answer (score 2):

As per my suggestion, the following could be an easy solution.
You should give class to all TR which you want to add in the count. The one you want to exclude from the summation will have a different id or a class. At the time of selection, you will select only those classes which you want to add om the summation.

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
function CalcularTotal () {
    var subtotal = 0;
    var total = 0;
    $("#tPedidos TBODY TR").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            Precio = row.find("TD").eq(1).find('input').val();
            CantidadPedido = row.find("TD").eq(2).find('input').val();
            subtotal = Precio * CantidadPedido;
            total += Number(subtotal);
            console.log(total);                
        });

        $("#tot").val(total);     
}
```

working solution:

```
function CalcularTotal () {
    var subtotal = 0;
    var total = 0;
    $("#tPedidos TBODY TR").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);

            if($(this) != $("#tPedidos TBODY TR:contains('Agregar otro Producto')")){
               Precio = row.find("TD").eq(1).find('input').val();
               CantidadPedido = row.find("TD").eq(2).find('input').val();
               subtotal = Precio * CantidadPedido;
               total += Number(subtotal);
               console.log(total);           
            }     
        });

        $("#tot").val(total);     
}
```

**UPDATE:** Now I had to use cheat to make it work

Comment: Im still getting the last row in the count

Comment: I think it is better to move `$("#tPedidos TBODY TR:last-child")` outside of the loop for performance, so condition should be something like `if (row != lastRow)`

Comment: what does `$("#tPedidos TBODY TR:last-child")` return in the console?

Comment: If you are talking about the value im getting in the last row still is a Nan @Shizukura

Comment: @Aux1234 I mean sometimes `last-child` returns 2 TR. you might want to check if changing `$("#tPedidos TBODY TR:last-child")` to `$("#tPedidos TBODY TR:last-child")[0]` or `$("#tPedidos TBODY TR:last-child")[1]`. if these doesn't work, i'll work on another solution

Comment: @Shizukura tried both and nothing, this is how my table looks https://imgur.com/a/N4TpKG9 where "Agregar otro Producto" is the last row in the table

Comment: @Aux1234 I updated the answer, you may try it. (though it doesn't look dynamic )

Comment: @Shizukura I managed to solve it with the solution above, but I really appreciate the help you gave me! Thank you so much!